# How to check if a polygon contains another polygon in OL3?

Tags: algorithm, geospatial, openlayers-3

Is there any possibility to check if a polygon is contained in another polygon in OL3?

I noticed there is a couple of methods in ol.extent e.g. ol.extent.containsExtent(extent1, extent2). But this checks only the extents and not the entire polygon. So in some cases I get "true" although the polygon is way outside the other polygon, but still in the extent...
What I need is a function or algorithm that checks if a polygon entirely contains another polygon like I usually do in any GIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenLayers 3 does not include a function to check if a polygon is inside another polygon. But you could use [JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts), the JavaScript port of [JTS Topology Suite](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html) to do the check:

```
    var feature1 = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Polygon(...));
    var feature2 = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Polygon(...));

    var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
    var geojsonReader = new jsts.io.GeoJSONReader();

    var polygon1Jsts = geojsonReader.read(
        format.writeFeatureObject(feature1)).geometry;
    var polygon2Jsts = geojsonReader.read(
        format.writeFeatureObject(feature2)).geometry;

    console.log(polygon1Jsts.contains(polygon2Jsts));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d6o81vc7/1/

See also: [jsts.geom.Geometry.html#contains](http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/doc/api/symbols/jsts.geom.Geometry.html#contains)

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with OL3, but:

If you have two polygons A & B, and all vertices of A are located within the area of B, then B contains A. Running `ol.extent.containsCoordinate` on each coordinate of a A should do the trick.

Side note: If B is concave (not sure this is the right form of the word to use here), this might not work...

Comment: this leads to the same problem, it only checks if a vertex of A is located in the extent of B